# How can I repair a broken key of a new MacBook Pro 15'' Retina 2015?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair, display

I have bought a new macbook pro 15" retina in March 2015, but with less than 1 month of usage, I feel that my enter key is very loose and probably (or almost) broken.

Maybe it's not broken and the quality of Macbook Pros is getting worse and things deteriorate really faster than the older ones.

Aesthetically the keyboard looks normal, but when typing, specially the enter feels horrible...I can't stop thinking I've spent 2K euros in something that is worse than cheap competitors.

The product is under warranty, but I don't know for sure if the authorised firms will do something about it — they might say that this behaviour is normal or that I used it badly (which is not true).

Has anyone had any exprience with this?
How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just take it to an Apple Store or an APR. My guess is that they'll just replace it within warranty terms.

Comment: I don't know if the keyboard is broken. It's working well, the feel when pressing the button is horrible, because I've compared with others people macbook pro 15, and the way the key comport themselves is totally different (more precise).

Comment: Could be dirt that slipped under the key.  You could try to get the key out. it's not that difficult to put it back in.  I've taken out hundreds of macbook keys over the years, yet to ruin the first one.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be the problem of keycap. The plastic part was broken.

Answer (score -1):

Apple has changed the keyboard mechanism, that is why it feels different when pressed.

> [Butterfly Mechanism](http://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2015/04/apples-invention-covering-the-butterfly-hinge-mechanism-found-in-their-new-macbook-keyboard-comes-to-light.html)
>
> Apple introduced the new MacBook keyboard butterfly mechanism this
>   way:
>
> Traditional keyboards use a scissor mechanism, which tends to wobble
>   around the edges. This creates a lack of precision when you strike
>   anywhere except the center of the key. We needed to reduce key
>   wobbling for a keyboard this thin; otherwise, striking a key
>   off-center could result in the keycap hitting bottom before a
>   keystroke registers. So we designed an entirely new butterfly
>   mechanism, which is wider than the scissor mechanism and has a single
>   assembly made from a stiffer material — allowing for a more stable,
>   responsive key that takes up less vertical space. This innovative
>   design improves stability, uniformity, and control — no matter where
>   you press on the key.

Comment: This user is specifically referring to the MacBook Pro. Furthermore, the device in question came out in March of 2015.